# Short horror/SF story where a farmer contacts an underground kingdom while digging a well?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about a farmer who digs a hole (possibly for a well) but breaks into an underground 'kingdom'.  He makes contact and exchanges messages with the people who live there via rope/bucket arrangement.  They ask for meat, he supplies chickens, they give him gold.  Later, they start asking for more meat (with the inference that human flesh is provided).  This has to date pre-1980 because I'm sure I read it while I was in primary school during the 1970s.

Anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old story about mysterious creatures at the bottom of a well that have a taste for "live turkey" (i.e. human flesh)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156779/old-story-about-mysterious-creatures-at-the-bottom-of-a-well-that-have-a-taste-f)

Comment: We only mark duplicates for story ID questions if both answers are confirmed. This answer has never been confirmed.

Answer (score 14):

This is almost certainly a television episode of Amazing Stories from the mid-1980s. The title was Thanksgiving, and starred David Carradine.

I can only find an excerpt on Youtube, despite watching the full episode there not a month ago:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5o3uUe238Y

Wikipedia lists those with teleplay credits, but does not say whether it was based on an earlier short story.

Managed to find the author of the original short story: Harold Rolseth.

The short is named *Hey You Down There!* Here is a link of dubious legality:

http://julie-cfahs.wikispaces.com/file/view/Hey+You+Down+There

Comment: The full series is at https://archive.org/details/AmazingStories. It was a good series.

Answer (score 4):

That is based off of the story *Hey You Down There* by Harold Rolseth which can be found in the book of short stories *Stories To Be Read In The Dark*.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the compilation 
Alfred Hitchcock Presents: Stories to Be Read With the Lights On

Comment: What elements match the question's description?