# TV show where something living in a well filled containers with gold and jewels?

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was a show in the 80s or early 90s.  The episode I remember was about a man and his daughter who found a well or a hole in the ground.  They would send a bucket down and something would fill it with gold and jewels.  The guy wanted to know what was down there so he went down, something ate him, and when the girl pulled him up his suit was full of jewels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short horror/SF story where a farmer contacts an underground kingdom while digging a well?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24174/short-horror-sf-story-where-a-farmer-contacts-an-underground-kingdom-while-diggi)

Answer (score 5):

This is a likely duplicate of [Short horror/SF story where a farmer contacts an underground kingdom while digging a well?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24174/7603).

From my previous answer:

This is almost certainly a television episode of Amazing Stories from the mid-1980s. The title was Thanksgiving, and starred David Carradine.

I can only find an excerpt on YouTube, despite watching the full episode there not a month ago:

Wikipedia lists those with teleplay credits, but does not say whether it was based on an earlier short story.

Managed to find the author of the original short story: Harold Rolseth.

The short is named *Hey You Down There!* Here is a link of dubious legality:

http://julie-cfahs.wikispaces.com/file/view/Hey+You+Down+There