# Short story: Ironic ending is a note ‘Send more chickens like that’

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

- A short story, mean farmer who finds a hole/cave that has aliens/monsters who give him gold in exchange for food
- Provides chickens
- Ends up disappearing
- Wife goes to cave/hole and receives a note asking for the more chicken like the last one - her husband

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance! Your question will be closed as a duplicate. It's not a censure on you, but just a matter of that it's how we organize our data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a dupe of [Old story about mysterious creatures at the bottom of a well that have a taste for "live turkey" (i.e. human flesh)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156779/old-story-about-mysterious-creatures-at-the-bottom-of-a-well-that-have-a-taste-f?noredirect=1&lq=1), which has the answer of "[Hey You, Down There](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48903748-hey-you-down-there)" by Harold Rolseth.

> - A farmer digs a new well and discovers some sort of civilization of 'monsters'.
> - The farmer and his wife/daughter feed the 'monsters' by lowering down a turkey in a bucket.
> - The 'monsters' communicate back with the farmer using notes.
> - The farmer descends into the well, curious about the 'monsters'.
> - The 'monsters' send a note back up the well, thanking the wife for the delicious meal.